# How to selecting subqueries correctly

Tags: select, subquery

I have two queries that give me back a single entry. How can I select both of these as on table?

query1: `Select max([column3]) from [table1] => 42`
query2: `Select Top 1 [column1] from [table1] => 'test'`

I want a resultset like this

| result1 | result2 |
| --- | --- |
| 42 | 'test' |

But how to do it correctly? Can I maybe select from nowhere somehow?

Comment: What is the `ORDER BY` clause you want to use with the `TOP` query (and note that order by is really mandatory) ?

Comment: yes sry i didnt mention it because my table index is the order I want for the `Top` query. So it would be `Order By [column1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`, twice:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column3 DESC) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY some_col) rn2
    FROM table1
)

SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN column3 END) AS result1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN column1 END) AS result2
FROM cte;
```

Note that I assume there exists a column `some_col` which you intend to use for choosing the `column1` value.